# Extending a tsquery after plain parsing it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, full-text-search

I want to do a prefix search with some user input. I first want to use `plainto_tsquery` to convert the user input to a `tsquery`, then convert it into a prefix search query.

I don't want to simply append `:*` to the input, as it might contain invalid SQL (and I don't want to just send user input into my database unescaped). How do I append `:*` to an already parsed `tsquery`? The `ts_rewrite` function doesn't seem to support this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a full text query containing invalid SQL? Maybe an example can help.

Comment: the `to_tsvector` function expects a valid query, like `foo:*`. It would fail on something like `foo bar` with a space in it.

Comment: I cannot think of a better way than regular expression magic on the query string before you parse it, but I understand if you don't like that.